# Looking for a review of the book Monoids, Acts and Categories

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, category-theory

I have been looking for a review of the following book:

[*Monoids, Acts and Categories with Applications to Wreath Products and Graphs* by Mati Kilp, Ulrich Knauer, Alexander V. Mikhalev](http://books.google.com/books?id=4gPhmmW-EGcC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)

but i was unable to find one. Does anybody have experience with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access to journals? Searching through my school's list of articles, there's something in

"SEMIGROUP FORUM Volume 66, Number 3, 489-490
DOI: 10.1007/s002330010145"
http://www.springerlink.com/content/k667uw3ehl5gxvbn/

and

"Bull. London Math. Soc. (2001) 33 (4): 505.
doi: 10.1017/S0024609301299287"
http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/33/4/505.full.pdf+html

I don't know if these are what you're looking for (they're not extremely long), and if you don't have access to the journals, I guess I'm probably not allowed to link the articles here. If you'd like me to email them to you or something, I can do that.

The material of the book is way beyond me, so unfortunately I don't have any experience with it, but I hope I could help anyway.

Comment: This looks very good, thank you. I do have access to journals. Will try it tomorrow and let you know :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Ben, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again :-)

Comment: The `springerlink.com` link is broken. The URL has changed to https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002330010145. (The `blms.oxfordjournals.org` URL has also changed: it redirects to https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/33/4/505/333162.)